# OpenGL crashes when I click the window and my animations aren't working as intended

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2012, and whenever I run my code to view my creation in the OpenGL window I can't click it or even click on the close window button without it crashing and me having to force close it.

This doesn't happen when I don't use animations (so when I just use keys to control movement), and when my animations do work they seem to only work randomly and not in the desired way.

Without changing any code, the last 3 times I ran my code: The first time it ran through all 3 stages of animation successfully, but got stuck on the first stage when I reset it. The second time it got stuck on the first animation. The third time it got stuck on the first stage again.

This my display function (including my 3 animate functions):

```
// GLUT display callback function
void Display(void)
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glLoadIdentity(); // transformations are represented by matrices
    // for placing camera
    gluLookAt(0,1,50,0,0,0,0,1,0);
    // for mouse movement
    glTranslatef(g_fTransX,g_fTransY,g_fZoom);
    glRotatef   (g_fSpinX,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef   (g_fSpinY,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,lpos);

    // xyz axes
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glLineWidth(2.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(20.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 20.0, 0.0);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 20.0);
    glEnd();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    float Ambient_m[] = {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_AMBIENT,Ambient_m);
    float Ambient_l[] = {0.2f,0.2f,0.2f,0.0f};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,Ambient_l);

    // implementing our custom cylinder function
    //draw_cylinder(g_translate_x, g_translate_y, g_dof3_angle);

    // our csg object with 4 DOF
    GLUquadricObj * qobj = gluNewQuadric();

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    //draw_lamp(g_dof3_angle);
    //glutSwapBuffers();

    /*animate(time_from, time_to, dof1_from, dof1_to,
    dof2_from, dof2_to, dof3_from, dof3_to,
    dof4_from, dof4_to, dof5_from, dof5_to,
    dof6_from, dof6_to, dof7_from, dof7_to)*/

    animate_lamp(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 45.0f, 0.0f, -45.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    animate_lamp(5.0f, 7.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f,
        0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        45.0f, -45.0f, -45.0f, 45.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    animate_lamp(7.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f,
        5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        45.0f, -45.0f, -45.0f, 45.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);



    //glutSwapBuffers(); // swap back buffer to front buffer (which is drawn on screen)

}
```

And this is my `animate_lamp()` function:

```
void animate_lamp(float time_from, float time_to, float dof1_from, float dof1_to,
     float dof2_from, float dof2_to, float dof3_from, float dof3_to,
     float dof4_from, float dof4_to, float dof5_from, float dof5_to,
     float dof6_from, float dof6_to, float dof7_from, float dof7_to){



_ftime64_s( &timebuffer );
        timeline = _ctime64( & ( timebuffer.time ) );
        int time2 = convert_total_msec((int) timebuffer.millitm, timeline);
        float diff_time = (float) (time2 - g_time1) / 1000.0f;
        while ( (time_from <= diff_time) && (diff_time-time_to) ) {

            float dof1_trans = (diff_time-time_from)/(time_to-time_from) * (dof1_to-dof1_from) + dof1_from;
            float dof2_trans = (diff_time-time_from)/(time_to-time_from) * (dof2_to-dof2_from) + dof2_from;
            float dof3_angle = (diff_time-time_from)/(time_to-time_from) * (dof3_to-dof3_from) + dof3_from;
            float dof4_angle = (diff_time-time_from)/(time_to-time_from) * (dof4_to-dof4_from) + dof4_from;
            float dof5_angle = (diff_time-time_from)/(time_to-time_from) * (dof5_to-dof5_from) + dof5_from;
            float dof6_angle = (diff_time-time_from)/(time_to-time_from) * (dof6_to-dof6_from) + dof6_from;
            float dof7_angle = (diff_time-time_from)/(time_to-time_from) * (dof7_to-dof7_from) + dof7_from;

            glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
            draw_lamp(dof1_trans, dof2_trans, dof3_angle, dof4_angle, dof5_angle, dof6_angle, dof7_angle);
            glutSwapBuffers();
            //
            _ftime64_s( &timebuffer );
            timeline = _ctime64( & ( timebuffer.time ) );
            time2 = convert_total_msec((int) timebuffer.millitm, timeline);
            diff_time = (float) (time2 - g_time1) / 1000.0f;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what the GLUT display callback is for.

It is supposed to render a single frame, NOT do an entire animation.

If you loop in `display()`, your program will not be able to handle any other events. A couple of seconds after you click in the window, Windows will notice that your program "doesn't respond" and offer to force close it.

To make the animation work properly, first add an idle callback:

```
void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// in main():
glutIdleFunc(&idle);
```

Then, make your `Display` function render only the "current" frame each time it is called.

Also, make sure you don't leak your `GLUquadricObj`;  you're creating a new one everytime Display is called, but you don't seem to free it. This will fill up your memory over time.

Comment: How would I make `Display` render only the "current" frame?

Comment: In your code, that would basically be the body of the while loop you have in animate_lamp. You will need to think about a data structure to keep track of the animation (or better yet, an object oriented design).